# If one travel tangentially through electric field, will the magnitude of electric field stay the same?

Tags: electromagnetism

"Tangential electric field component is continuous across the surface".(See: i.e. http://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e171f00/lectures/boundary.pdf ) Consider the space as a "stack of surfaces" of the same media, where the electric field is parallel to the surface(or say the surface extend in the same direction of the electric field).

If one travel tangentially through the electric field, will the $E$ field always be the same?(Consider weird geometry, at which can be reduced/approximated by Euclidean locally.)

I think it's the case, but I'm not quite sure how to prove it.(Maybe write $E=\nabla A$?)

Comment: Where is the quotation from?

Comment: @N.Steinle http://home.sandiego.edu/~ekim/e171f00/lectures/boundary.pdf It's the boundary condition of electric field. It's everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, but you should cite a quotation in your question directly.

Comment: Thank you for editing it. Ive been trying to understand your question but it's not clear yet. "If one travel tangentially through the electric field, will the E field always be the same?" Are you asking if in general the tangential component of E will be uniform (independent of position)?

Comment: @N.Steinle No, just smooth, thus it can be tracked deferentially.

Comment: So you're wondering if the tangential component of the electric field near the surface of a conductor is continuous?

Comment: @N.Steinle No, but if traveling along the tangential component will maintain the same field strength.(A seemly much stronger case.)

Answer (score 1):

The assertion is not only true for a tangential electric field, what it really means is that the *tangential component* of the electric field has the same value in both materials over the surface.

In order to prove this assertion, you can use Faraday's law over a closed path where part of the closed path lies over the boundary of two materials:

$$\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}  = - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$$

Let us rotate the two materials so that the surface that separates them is horizontal. It doesn't matter whether the closed path lies just below or just above the boundary, $\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}$ must be equal in both cases because $ \iint_{\Sigma} \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}$ is the same (the difference of the area encircled by both circuits is the same taking the limit where the closed paths approach the boundary).